# How to use the index of one array to define __getitem__ of another?

Tags: python, oop, slice

I have an object of custom class `Field` that essentially wraps around a `numpy.ndarray` object. The object is defined from two inputs : an array of values (`values`) and a slice object (`segment`) that defines where those values should be placed in some larger array (`grid`).

I would like to be able to use the indexes of `grid` to access the items of `values`. This should be possible by defining a custom `Field.__getitem__` method.

```
import numpy as np

class Field:
    def __init__(self, values, segment, grid):
        if (not isinstance(segment, slice)) \\
        or (not isinstance(values, np.ndarray)) :
            raise TypeError
        if segment.step not in [1, -1]:
            raise ValueError('Segment must be continuous')
        if len(grid[segment]) != len(values):
            raise ValueError('values length must match segment')

        self.values = values
        self.segment = segment 
        self.grid = grid

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        new_key = ...  # <--- Code goes here
        return self.values[new_key]

grid = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])

values = np.array([42., 43., 44.])
segment = slice(2, 5)

my_field = Field(values, segment, grid)
print(grid[segment])  # output: [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
print(my_field[2])  # Desired output: 42.
print(my_field[3])  # Desired output: 43.
print(my_field[0])  # Desired output: IndexError
```

The point is that `segment` defines the set of positions in `grid` where `my_field` is defined.
The way I approached this has turned out to be very inelegant and clumsy and was based on defining some array of boolean `index = np.zeros_like(grid, dtype=bool); index[segment] = True` and then involved some tricks with `np.cumsum(index)` ...

**How can I achieve this behavior in a simpler way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your slice with an explicit step:

```
segment = slice(2, 5, 1)
```

This is to ensure `segment.step` in your `__init__` returns `1`. Then define a method which checks whether your input `key` is in the appropriate `range`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    start, stop = self.segment.start, self.segment.stop
    new_key = key - start
    if new_key not in range(stop - start):
        raise IndexError(f'Key must be in range({start}, {stop})')
    return self.values[new_key]
```

This gives:

```
my_field = Field(values, segment, grid)
print(grid[segment])  # [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
print(my_field[2])    # 42.0
print(my_field[3])    # 43.0
print(my_field[0])    # IndexError: Key must be in range(2, 5)
```

Comment: Good point about `segment.step` ! Alternatively I can check a posteriori with `if segment.step not in [1, -1, None]` so that user needs not to know about this detail.

Comment: Another thing. To make this work with `segment = slice(None,)` (which would mean that `my_field` has the same indices as `grid`), one may redefine `self.segment` as: `self.segment = slice(segment.start or 0, segment.stop if segment.stop is not None else len(grid), segment.step or 1)`

Comment: @Alexis, Sure, my preference is to define `self.step= self.segment.stop`, then `if self.segment.step is None: self.step = 1`. Then work with `self.step` and avoid ternary statements in logic.

Comment: yup, trying to hard for a one liner :-)